# Power series for $|z|$ outside radius of convergence diverges

Tags: complex-analysis

I have proved that if $|z| > R$ then the power series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty |a_nz^n| = \infty.$ However, I have trouble showing that the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nz^n$ diverges as a result. I first tried assuming that $\sum_{n =0}^\infty a_nz^n = L$ converges. I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Any hints?

Comment: Start by showing that if the series converges for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then it converges whenever $|z_0| < |z|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence is given by

$$R^{-1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(|a_n| \right)^{1/n} $$

If $|z| > R$ then

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(|a_nz^n| \right)^{1/n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(|a_n| \right)^{1/n}|z| = \frac{|z|}{R} >1, $$

and $|a_nz^n| > 1$ infinitely often. This  implies that the series diverges since $a_nz^n \not\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $|\sqrt[n]{a_n}z| > 1$ your series diverges by the root test.
If $|\sqrt[n]{a_n}z| < 1$ your series converges.

If $|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} z| > 1$ your series diverges by the ratio test.
If $|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} z| < 1$ your series converges.

If you haven't proven these, run a comparison test to a geometric series with a similar growth rate to prove divergence / convergence.